# How to add default options to a float environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I want my `tikz` images to have a different font. How can I change my `tikzpicture` environment, such that, by default it will call the `sansmath` environment and select the right font family.

Now it looks like this (MWE):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{PTSansNarrow-TLF} %Changes the default sans serif font, used for figures.
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sansmath}
        \fontfamily{PTSansNarrow-TLF}{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[xlabel = Period ($\pi$), ylabel = Amplitude ($\Omega$)]
                \addplot {sin(deg(x))}; 
            \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{sansmath}  
\end{document}
```

And I want to end up with something, such that I can do it like this:

```
\begin{newenvironment}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = Period ($\pi$), ylabel = Amplitude ($\Omega$)]
        addplot {sin(deg(x))}; 
    \end{axis} 
\end{newenvironment}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual `\newenvironment` will work here.  The syntax is

```
\newenvironment{environmentname}{initial material}{final material}
```

In your case you can write

```
\newenvironment{myplot}{\begin{sansmath}
  \fontfamily{PTSansNarrow-TLF}\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont
  \begin{tikzpicture}
}{\end{tikzpicture}\end{sansmath}}
```

to get a newenvironment `myplot`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{PTSansNarrow-TLF} %Changes the default sans serif font, used for figures.
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}

\newenvironment{myplot}{\begin{sansmath}
  \fontfamily{PTSansNarrow-TLF}\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont
  \begin{tikzpicture}
}{\end{tikzpicture}\end{sansmath}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myplot}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel = Period ($\pi$), ylabel = Amplitude ($\Omega$)]
    \addplot {sin(deg(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{myplot}

\end{document}
```